# Как получить последний символ из переменной?

Tags: php, modx, revo

```
echo "[[*id]]"; //выводит 671
```

Как отсюда выделить последний символ -1?

```
$str = '[[*id]]';
echo $str; // 671
$last = substr($str,-1);
echo $last; //выводит ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$str = $modx->resource->get('id');
echo $str;
$last = substr($str,-1);
echo $last;
```

Дело в том, что в вашем примере $str присваивается строка "[[*id]]" а потом уже парсер modx ее преобразует в id страницы

P.S. Исправил ответ, пропустил, что вы хотите получить ид страницы с которой вызываете сниппет. Просто, если вызывать сниппет с каким либо параметром например:

```
[[mysnippet?&myvar=`aaa`]]
```

То в php вы можете обращаться к этому параметру через переменную `$myvar`

Comment: пустая строка получается

Comment: Исправил ответ.